My Node.js app is crashing when I import my Node router
My Node.js server is crashing when I import the node routes. When I remove the routes, it works. I have tried to find the problem but I couldn’t. The path is actually correct when I double checked. Here is my code:
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import verifyRouter from "./routes/jwtauth";
    


const app = express();
const port = 4500;


// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.use("/auth", verifyRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
  });

Here is the error:
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\myproject\server\routes\jwtauth' imported from C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\myproject\server\index.js
Did you mean to import ../routes/jwtauth.js?
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:327:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:946:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1132:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.18.2
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

How can I check what is wrong?

import verifyRouter from "./routes/jwtauth.js"; ? try

May we see package.json added to your question? Ideally this is supplied as text, formatted as code.

rename import verifyRouter from "./routes/jwtauth"; to import verifyRouter from "./routes/jwtauth.js";
more...

what's the difference? Why the obscured link? What do I find at that link, it may go bad
